# No implementation found for int

Tags: android

Estou tendo problemas ao tentar usar algumas libs extras no meu projeto tenho uma pasta JNI e ou OBJ ambas tem os arquivos necessários, só que a hora que clico no botão para executar a ação acontece este erro.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ja resolvi algo semelhante utilizando a seguinte linha de código em combinação com uma thread que fazia um delay de uns 5 segundos:

```
            System.loadLibrary("SuaLibAqui");
```

mas esse mesmo código me dava a exceção UnsatisfiedLinkError que está algumas linhas abaixo no seu logcat, e a forma que resolvi foi colocar o código acima para carregar a lib durante uma splash screen.

Comment: Muito obrigado mas resolvi, deixei a bibliotecas apenas como lib, por que dentro dela tinha uma activity que usava a lib para rodar o app, então deletei o arquivo principal, setei o project como lib e utilizei os conceitos da activity que deletei e funcionou perfeitamente! Já que não manjava de mexer com JNI... eu tentei esses System.loadLibrary mas não funcionou pq a libs em C estavam compiladas para aquele pacote em especifico! Abração !